# Return specific value of all objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The following code returns only the "name" of the first item in the array "category". However I need it to return the "name" value of each item in the array.

What am I missing?

```
function loadCategories(id){
   for (var i = 0; i<folder.grades.models.length; i++){
      if(folder.grades.models[i].attributes.entityid==id) {
         return folder.grades.models[i].attributes.categories.category[i].name;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same `i` as an index into both `models` and `category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadCategories(id){
   var items = folder.grades.models;
   for (var i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
      if(items[i].attributes.entityid==id) {
         return items[i].attributes.categories.category.map(function(c) {
            return c.name;
         });
      }
   }
   return [];
}
```

Comment: Curious.. If I wanted to also get another property such as the "age" of the category and not only the name, would I need to write another function or for loop within the current function?

Comment: You could replace `return c.name;` with `return [c.name, c.age]`;

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits the function, you should add all names to an array and then return that array

```
function loadCategories(id){
   var names = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<folder.grades.models.length; i++){
      if(folder.grades.models[i].attributes.entityid==id) {
         names[i] = folder.grades.models[i].attributes.categories.category[i].name;
      }
   }
   return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return statements break out of functions, so once it hits that return statement, the function is over. If you want all of the names of the categories that match entity id:

```
function loadCategories(id){
   var result = [];
   for (var i = 0; i<folder.grades.models.length; i++){
      if(folder.grades.models[i].attributes.entityid==id) {
         for (var j = 0; j < folder.grades.models[i].attributes.categories.category.length; ++j) {
            result.push(folder.grades.models[i].attributes.categories.category[j].name);
         }
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```